# How to get date from two tables using trigger before insert into third table?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, compiler-errors, database-trigger

I'm trying to create a trigger `TrgDisAmount` to read `PROD_NAME` and `PRICE` from `PRODUCT` table and to calculate the `DISCOUNT` and `AMOUNT` of `SALES` Table for every new row inserted with the values of `SERIAL` and `PCODE`.

These are the tables information

```
Table SALES (SERIAL, PCODE, PROD_NAME, PRICE, DISCOUNT, AMOUNT)

Table PRODUCT (PCODE, PROD_NAME, PROD_CAT, PRICE)

Table DISCOUNT (PROD_CAT, DISCOUNT_RATE)
```

**Note:**

1. Enter the values for `SERIAL` and `PCODE` only, the remaining columns should entered by the trigger `TrgDisAmount` only
2. Get the `DISCOUNT_RATE` using Function `GetDiscount`.

I have already created `GetDiscount` function to get `DISCOUNT_RATE` from table `DISCOUNT`.

This is my try:

```
create or replace trigger TrgDisAmount
  before insert on SALES for each row
begin
  if :new.PCODE = :old.PRODUCT.PCODE then

    :new.PROD_NAME := :old.PRODUCT.PROD_NAME;
    :new.PRICE := :old.PRODUCT.PRICE;
    :new.DISCOUNT := :old.product.PRICE / (GetDiscount(:old.PRODUCT.PROD_CAT));
    :new.AMOUNT := :new.PRICE - :new.DISCOUNT;
  end if;

  insert into SALES columns (PROD_NAME, PRICE, DISCOUNT, AMOUNT) 
  values (:new.PROD_NAME, :new.PRICE, :new.DISCOUNT, :new.AMOUNT);
end;
/
```

When I run that block it shows me this error:

```
PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'OLD.PRODUCT'
```

I use `Table_Name.Column_name` to reach to the specific column. Is it legal to do it?

---

Sample output should be like this:

```
SQL> insert into sales values (1,'MB-101',null, null, null, null);

Result in SALES table:
   SERIAL : 1,
   PCODE : MB-101,
   PROD_NAME : IPHONE 6+,
   PRICE : 250 ,
   DISCOUNT : 25,
   AMOUNT : 225
```

Comment: What is the problem with your code?  Does it generate an error?  Does it do the wrong thing?

Comment: When i run that block it show me error says: PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'OLD.PRODUCT' @GordonLinoff

Comment: Correct these errors are - 1.Remove :OLD 2. call your function correctly and 3. remove INSERT INTO Clause. For Before insert trigger INSERT Statement is not required, when condition matches, a row is automatically inserted. Code snippet below  @user125150

Answer (score 1):

When you create a *before insert* trigger, you only have to set the `:new` values.  You don't actually insert into the table.  That is the next step in the processing.

Also, in an `insert` trigger, only refer to the `:new` values, not the `:old`.  There is no `:old` value, which is the specific error you are getting.

Then, you need to do a query to get the relevant information from the other tables.  The result should look something like this:

```
create or replace trigger TrgDisAmount
before insert on SALES
for each row
begin
    select p.price / d.discount into :new.discount
    from product p join
         discount d
         on p.prod_cat = d.prod_cat
    where :new.pcode = p.pcode;
    :new.AMOUNT := :new.PRICE - :new.DISCOUNT;
end;
```

The arithmetic for defining the discount looks very suspicious.  A 10% discount would be represented as 1.11 using this methodology.  However, this is the arithmetic in your question and you provide no sample data to suggest any other method.

Comment: how can i get data from other tables?  please see the update part in the question ,, SQL statement and its result @GordonLinoff

Comment: @user125150 . . . This query properly uses a `SELECT` to get data from other tables.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try changing , the way you are calling your function.

As mentioned by Gordon, :old shouldn't be used in this case

```
CREATE or replace trigger TrgDisAmount 
Before insert 
on SALES 
for each row 

DECLARE
v_prod_cat varchar2(20);

BEGIN 

select PROD_NAME into :NEW.PROD_NAME
from PRODUCT 
where PRODUCT.PCODE = :NEW.PCODE;  

select  PRICE into :NEW.PRICE 
from PRODUCT 
where PRODUCT.PCODE = :NEW.PCODE; 

select  PROD_CAT into v_prod_cat from discount where  PROD_CAT 
in( select PROD_CAT from PRODUCT where  PCODE = :NEW.PCODE); 

select  GetDiscount(v_prod_cat) into :NEW.discount from dual;

 :new.AMOUNT := :new.PRICE - :new.DISCOUNT;

END;
/

Trigger created.   
SQL> show err;                                                        
 No errors.

insert into sales  values(701,1,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);
```

[image]

Comment: please see the update part in the question @mahendar-mahi

Comment: @user125150 Did you try it this way?